# Trying to recover Websocket Connection

Tags: go, websocket

I'm using [this library](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket). After few hours or a day the websocket.JSON.Recieve will error and will get an EOF. I connect to the web socket again and no problems, but then I just keep getting EOF until I restart my application.

```
func getMessage(ws *websocket.Conn) (m Message, err error) {
    err = websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Get Message - %s - Reconnecting...", err)
        ws, _ = connect(token) // This just does a dial
        err = websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &m)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: >the websocket.JSON.Recieve will error. |
and what error is it?

Comment: @Darigaaz the error just says "EOF". I've seen other people using this library and nobody tries to recover from it, I've only seen people completely close their application when they get any error or some that specifically close the application on "EOF".

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is it is somehow related to "max open files". It is a long shot but give it a try.

Your server/lib does not close/release ended/staled connections properly.

Its OS specific but i guess you are using Linux.
So next time you problem happens (before you restart your app) can you run

```
# lsof -p PID | wc -l
# lsof -a -p PID | wc -l
```

OR

```
# cd /proc/PID/fd; ls -l | wc -l
```

where PID is your server application PID on server's console? And post it along with `lsof -a -p PID` here via link to gist or something (since i am expecting long list).

Find PID with `# ps aux | grep APPNAME` or `# pidof APPNAME`.

You can check server wide "max open files" with

```
sysctl fs.file-max
```

If it is the case you can increase max open files with `sysctl -w fs.file-max= 100000` but it will just delay the inevitable, or dig into the code and handle these unterminated connections.

Usefull links [list open files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html), [max open files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) or google yourself.